# How can I transfer my bitcoins from my wallet to a market place?

Tags: wallet, trade

I got a bitcoin coupon as a gift. I got the bitcoins into my wallet (Bread). Now I would like to transfer those coins into a market place like eToro or similar to start by selling some of them. I haven't found a way how to do that so far. Any help would be very welcome.

Comment: Hi and welcome! The marketplace typically requires you to send the bitcoins to an address of theirs, and the in return send the money to your bank account.

Answer (score 1):

Marketplaces (as well as ATM's for this matter) typically require you to **send the bitcoins to an address of theirs**. As soon as that transaction confirms, they send you cash via a traditional bank account, paypal etc...

Any trustworthy marketplace will describe that process in detail. Here is some information from btcdirect, for example: https://btcdirect.eu/en-ie/purchase-order